# How to treat a datacontext as a certain type in WPF XAML designer?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, xaml, devexpress

I have a `GridControl` and a `LayoutPanel`, I wish the contents of the `LayoutPanel` to be bound to the selected item in the grid, so what do I do, I bind to the `CurrentItem` of the `GridControl`, but oh no, the `VS WPF XAML` designer does not know what type the `CurrentItem` is, since its some kind of generic type specific to the `GridControl`... so I now get those squiggly lines telling me off.

```
    <GridControl Name="CustomersGrid" .../>
    <LayoutPanel DataContext="{Binding CurrentItem, ElementName=CustomersGrid}">
<dxdo:LayoutControlItem Caption="Code">
<dxe:TextEdit IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding Code}" /> // sqiggly here
</dxdo:LayoutControlItem>
    </LayoutPanel>
```

To make the issue a bit worse, the type is coming from WCF, so its not in my immediate project. So the question is, how can I make the designer happy and treat the `CurrentItem` as one of my own known types, ie. `Customer`, so that it recognised that `Code` belongs to it.

Comment: Can you give an example of your viewmodel class that binds to that grid?